# function to calculate Target after joining ration from other data farame

Tags: r, dplyr

I Have two data frames for is sales data with many different columns and another is incentive scale data .

I am trying to map scale against goals in sales data , then I am trying to recalculate Target columns against incentive scale . but unable to create the perfect logic to do this .

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("ABC",    "DCA",  "GOL",  "LAM",  "MNA",  "BVA",  "VAN"),
                 Goal =c("published",   "pending",  "not designed",NA,  "pending",  "pending",  "not designed"),
                 Target_1 = c(3734, 2639,   2604,   NA, 2793,   2688,   2403),
                 Target_2 = c(3322, 2016,   2310,   NA, 3236,   3898,   2309),
                 Target_3 = c(3785, 2585,   3750,   NA, 2781,   3589,   2830))


df1 <- data.frame(Goals = c("published",    "pending",  "not designed"),
                  Incentive =c(1.4,1.1,0.5))
df <- left_join(df,df1,by=c("Goal"="Goals")) %>% relocate(Incentive,.after = Goal) %>%
  mutate(colnames(contains("Target")) =  colnames(contains("Target"))*Incentive)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `across` -

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df,df1,by=c("Goal"="Goals"))  %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Target"), ~. * Incentive))

#  Name         Goal Target_1 Target_2 Target_3 Incentive
#1  ABC    published   5227.6   4650.8   5299.0       1.4
#2  DCA      pending   2902.9   2217.6   2843.5       1.1
#3  GOL not designed   1302.0   1155.0   1875.0       0.5
#4  LAM         <NA>       NA       NA       NA        NA
#5  MNA      pending   3072.3   3559.6   3059.1       1.1
#6  BVA      pending   2956.8   4287.8   3947.9       1.1
#7  VAN not designed   1201.5   1154.5   1415.0       0.5
```

Comment: while applying to my original data i am getting this error       Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.

Comment: i forgot to put i want to do calculation on numeric columns have target only, trying like this but not working.

 mutate(across(where(is.numeric(.cols = contains("Terget") ,
                .fns = ~ . *Incentive))))

Comment: It means some of the column in your original data are not numeric. Check `str(df)` and `str(df1)` to confirm their class. You can change their class  and perform calculation.  `left_join(df,df1,by=c("Goal"="Goals")) %>%
  mutate(across(c(contains("Target"),Incentive), as.numeric), 
         across(contains("Target"), ~. * Incentive))`

Comment: yes i get get to know that one column have character values so how can i filter that column before calculation...?

Comment: There are multiple ways in which you can select columns in `across` but it is not clear to me which columns you want to multiply and which ones you don't. For eg - All the columns that has `Target` in it except `Target_1` can be written as - `across(c(contains("Target"), -Target_1), ~. * Incentive)`. To include all the numeric columns  you can do `across(where(is.numeric), ~. * Incentive)`. Let me know if it helps or if you need anymore clarification.